# Pandas Resizing dataframe after a pivot?

Tags: python, pandas

I pivoted some data and I ended up with something like:

```
                TotalOrder
        Date    2017-01-01 2017-01-02 2017-01-03 2017-01-04
Company Region
ABD     SW      76.4       47.25      45.54      74.2
DEF     NE      73.3       54.23      76.23      23.2
WEW     S       76.7       54.32      12.34      56.2
```

I would like to make it so it's just:

```
Company Region  2017-01-01 2017-01-02 2017-01-03 2017-01-04
ABD     SW      76.4       47.25      45.54      74.2
DEF     NE      73.3       54.23      76.23      23.2
WEW     S       76.7       54.32      12.34      56.2
```

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Does `df.columns = df.columns.droplevel(0)` solve your issue?

Comment: No, that keeps all the dates but drops `Company` and `Region`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date` is the name of the second level of the `pd.MultiIndex` object that occupies the `columns` attribute.  `TotalOrder` is the first level of that `pd.MultiIndex`.

Some of this you can fix by calling your pivot ever so slightly differently.  However, since you didn't post that part, let's fix what you have.

```
df['TotalOrder'].rename_axis(None, 1).reset_index()

  Company Region  2017-01-01  2017-01-02  2017-01-03  2017-01-04
0     ABD     SW        76.4       47.25       45.54        74.2
1     DEF     NE        73.3       54.23       76.23        23.2
2     WEW      S        76.7       54.32       12.34        56.2
```

Or with a little more gymnastics involved

```
df.T.reset_index(0, drop=True).rename_axis(None).T.reset_index()

  Company Region  2017-01-01  2017-01-02  2017-01-03  2017-01-04
0     ABD     SW        76.4       47.25       45.54        74.2
1     DEF     NE        73.3       54.23       76.23        23.2
2     WEW      S        76.7       54.32       12.34        56.2
```

Answer (score 0):

you can slice the dataframe using loc() function like

```
df = dataFrame.loc['ABD':'WEW']
df3 = DataFrame(data=df,columns=['Company', 'Region', '2017-01-01', '2017-01-02', '2017-01-03','2017-01-04'])
```